# Convert .tex file into PNG without ImageMagick

Tags: linux, png, unix

I'm noob in TeX. Would it be possible to convert a `.tex` file into PNG without installing ImageMagick? Is there a standalone method that I can use?

Comment: Printscreen button? Won't be great quality, though

Comment: Did you mean to write, "Convert *a pdf file generated by* tex into PNG without installing ..." (emphasis added)?

Comment: Google the words "convert pdf to png online" (without the quotes) to see many possibilities for online converting, of which I have tried none.

Comment: How can this be off topic?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Could you say what you mean by 'standalone'? There is some confusion among readers about this: the question suggests you just mean 'without installing ImageMagick' but you might mean 'without installing ImageMagick, a TeX distribution or any similar software' in which case, we need to know what counts as 'similar' ;).

Comment: `tex_to_images` can turn fragments of LaTeX files into images. Although it does not produce PNG directly, you could easily convert to PNG without needing ImageMagick.

Comment: @egreg no, I do not know dvipng. But I think the question was tex to png without steps between.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, it's surely possible. The TeX Live distribution features the `dvipng` program. Here's a sample.

### LaTeX file `test.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\kant[1]
\end{document}
```

### Convert to DVI `test.dvi`

```
latex test
```

### Convert to PNG `test1.png`

```
dvipng -T tight test
```

### Output

[image]

Consult the manual for more information about command line options.

Comment: And how will the executables `latex` and `dvipng` be available without installing anything?

Comment: @PaulGessler I assume a TeX system.

Comment: @egreg Why the proliferation of ImageMagick method, then?  I couldn't get `convert` to work.  Will use this method.  Thanks!

Comment: @FruitfulApproach Unfortunately, this method has very limited usefulness when graphics, such as TikZ, is involved.